# Different fill behavior inside a Path GeometryGroup

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is a very simplified version of my xaml :

```
<Path>
  <Path.Data>
    <GeometryGroup>
      <EllipseGeometry/>
      <EllipseGeometry/>
    </GeometryGroup>
   </Path.Data>  
</Path>
```

I would like the first `EllipseGeometry` to be filled, but not the second one. But the `Fill` property is defined at the `Path`'s level.

I could define two `Paths` each containing an `EllipseGeometry` but I want them to share the path's `Stroke`. The `Path`'s stroke is going to be modified by a trigger so I can't use a `StaticResource`. I also don't want to have to duplicate the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the stroke in a shared style and use two Paths:

```
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Path">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="AliceBlue" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Canvas.Resources>
        <Path Fill="Green">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry />
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="Red">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry />
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
```

This way you can define the stroke in one place and the fills separately. Of course you don't have to use a canvas as the container.

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: In fact I was using `EllipseGeometry` because of their `Center` property which is more convenient than using a trick like a negative `Margin` on an `Ellipse`..

Comment: I've modified my answer to the more obvious solution. Does this work?